# When does EF know the SQL statement it uses?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

We're working on logging the SQL statements that Entity Framework uses against the database. We're using SQL Server 2012.

I've done some experimenting to learn how this is done by assigning a delegate to the `Database.Log` property of the `DbContext` object. In my customer logger I've found that I can easily get to the SQL statement that is produced by EF when it does an `INSERT` / `UPDATE` / `DELETE`, and I presume a `SELECT` as well (although at this point I've been focusing upon just inserts, updates and deletes).

But unless I'm mistaken (always possible) it seems to me as though the delegate only has access to the SQL generated by EF, after the fact. Am I correct about that? If so, at what point does EF "know" what the SQL statement is going to be?

(I should mention that at this point we're running directly against the tables; we're not using stored procedures. That might happen down the road, but not at this time.)

Comment: Finalizing the SQL should be the last thing it does before sending it to the Db. So, I guess the short answer is, it knows what the SQL is going to be just before it sends it.

Comment: Ah, so there's a possibility that I might be able to get access to the SQL statement just before EF executes it. Thank you! I wonder how I get access to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can intercept commands (and modify them) just before they are send using the interception interface. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx for an overview and http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/database-command-interception.aspx for an implementation.

Since you can write code before and after execution your are quite capable of writing detailed logging. It is more flexible than using Database.Log. That gives you basically a string to use but using interceptors you are free to do whatever you want with all the relevant information that is available.

Comment: Thank you Peter, this looks very promising.

Comment: Peter, I've got a follow-up question for you. I've read through the intro and the implementation pages. Downloaded the 2 samples from the implementation site. The thing I noticed is that one of the samples does EF database first, the other one does EF code first. We've created a .EDMX file; will these interceptor commands work in our situation, or would it be better if we did a code-first with existing database?

Comment: Never mind; I see the EFDBFirstTutorials uses a .edmx file.